# ¿Se puede convertir un rgb a su nombre?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quisiera saber si es posible transformar un RGB a NOMBRE.
Por ejemplo:

```
from matplotlib import colors

print(colors.to_rgb('blue'))
>>(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

La idea es así, pero pasarlo a su nombre..

```
print(colors.to_name(0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
>>'blue'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que no cualquier tupla "rgb" tiene un nombre asignado. Y luego están posibles errores de redondeo por tener cada componente "rgb" como un float entre 0 y 1, cuando en realidad los nombres de los colores están definidos en hexadecimal con componentes enteras entre 0 y 255.

Pero salvando esos problemas una idea es la siguiente:

En `matplotlib.colors.cnames` tienes un diccionario en el que a cada nombre de color se le asocia su valor rgb hex. Por ejemplo, un trozo de ese diccionario es:

```
{'aliceblue': '#F0F8FF',
 'antiquewhite': '#FAEBD7',
 'aqua': '#00FFFF',
 'aquamarine': '#7FFFD4',
 'azure': '#F0FFFF',
  # etc...
}
```

A partir de él podemos crear otro "inverso" en el que las claves sean las componentes RGB y los valores los colores. Ya de paso convierto la forma hex a una tupla con tres valores enteros (de 0 a 255):

```
def rgb2tuple(rgb):
    return tuple(int(component, 16)
            for component in (rgb[1:3], rgb[3:5], rgb[5:7]))

cnames_rev = { rgb2tuple(rgb): name for name, rgb in colors.cnames.items() }
```

Un trozo de este diccionario sería:

```
{
 (25, 25, 112): 'midnightblue',
 (30, 144, 255): 'dodgerblue',
 (32, 178, 170): 'lightseagreen',
 (34, 139, 34): 'forestgreen',
 (46, 139, 87): 'seagreen',
 # ...etc
}
```

Ahora ya es sencillo hacer la función que pides:

```
def colors_to_name(color):
  rgb = tuple(int(c*255) for c in color)
  return cnames_rev.get(rgb, "Unknown")
```

Ejemplo:

```
ej = colors.to_rgb('yellowgreen')
print(ej)
print(colors_to_name(ej))
```

y sale `yellowgreen`.

## Ampliacion

Un problema interesante sería si tal tupla no aparece en nuestro diccionario inverso, entonces retornar la más cercana, y quizás una medida del error.

Esto se resuelve con las siguientes funciones:

```
import math

def distance(c1, c2):
    # Distancia euclídea (pitágoras)
    (r1,g1,b1) = c1
    (r2,g2,b2) = c2
    return math.sqrt((r1 - r2)**2 + (g1 - g2) ** 2 + (b1 - b2) **2)

def colors_to_name(color):
  # Convertirlo a números 0-255
  rgb = tuple(int(c*255) for c in color)

  # Mirar si ese color existe d forma exacta
  name = cnames_rev.get(rgb, None)
  if name is not None:
    return name, 0     # La distancia es cero en ese caso

  # Si no existe, buscamos el más cercano
  ordenados_por_distancia = sorted(cnames_rev.keys(), key=lambda c: distance(c,rgb))
  mejor = ordenados_por_distancia[0]

  # Retornamos el nombre y la distancia como un valor entre 0 (cerca) y 1 (muy lejos)
  return rev.get(mejor), distance(color, mejor)/(3*255**2)
```

Ejemplo, la tupla `(0.6039215686274509, 0.803921568627451, 0.19607843137254902)` representa *exactamente* el color "yellowgreen":

```
>>> colors_to_name((0.6039215686274509, 0.803921568627451, 0.19607843137254902))
('yellowgreen', 0)
```

Pero una aproximación razonable también funciona:

```
>>> colors_to_name((0.604, 0.804, 0.196))
('yellowgreen', 0.0013338729237875261)
```

Comment: Gracias, se entendió bastante, en la función ´colors_to_name´ tuve que ponerle "cnames_rev.get"

Comment: @LucasDamian Gracias. Corregido el fallo. Y ampliada la respuesta para cubrir el caso "aproximado".

Comment: Mi +1 por tan detallada respuesta. Dan ganas de meterle duro al Python